# C object with () - what does it do?

Tags: c++

What does this particular piece of code do? To be more precise, what does test tob(); do?

```
class test {
 private:
  int a;
  int b;
 public:
  test (int);
  test();
};
test::test() {
 cout<<"default";
}
test::test (int x=0) {
 cout<<"default x=0";
}
int main() {
 test tob();
}
```

I dont know what does test tob(); do, but it isn't giving any compilation errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
test tob();
```

This **declares** a function which return type is `test`. **It does not create an object.** It's also know as [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

To create a `test` object:

```
test tob;
```

Also, the way you define a function(include constuctor) with default argument is incorrect.

```
test::test (int x=0) {  // incorrect. You should put it in function when it's first declared
 cout<<"default x=0";
}
```

Below code should work:

```
class test {
  int a;
  int b;

 public:
  explicit test (int = 0);    // default value goes here
};

test::test (int x) {          
 cout<<"default x=0";
}

int main() {
 test tob;    // define tob object
}
```

Comment: This is not what's known as *most* vexing parse. This is just vexing. :)

Comment: @hvd Absolutely but this piece of misinformation seems very presistent. I suppose ultimately words mean what people use them for, so in time this will be the most vexing parse, despite it not being nearly as vexing as the original.

Comment: Here's the real most vexing parse, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse